# CSS3 Keyframes Issue

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

So I am trying to get an fade in effect where I want the fade in opacity to start off from 0 and go to 1 but then when it gets played the second time I want it to start from 0.5 and get played to 1. If you need more explanation then please let me know. I have inserted the code below. Thanks

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCustom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
    1%{
      opacity: 0.1;
  }
      10%{
      opacity: 0.2;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInCustom {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1%{
      opacity: 0.1;
  }
        10%{
      opacity: 0.2;
  }
    30% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code into JsFiddle?

Comment: @Joci93 I cannot do that because of company policy but is there no other way of doing this?